# Regex: Delete all html tags inside 2 other tags, except <a href=.*?"> and </a>

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to delete all html tags inside 2 other tags, except `<a href=.*?">` and `</a>`

For example:

```
<p class="mb-40px">Another blending </h2>option is to all the <div>brushstrokes to show. In the painting of trees above, I didn’t spend much time trying to <a href=https://orfun.com/acrylic class="color-bebe" target="_new">blend the colors</a>. I simply mix each color and apply it without fussing with it.</p>
```

**Output:**

```
<p class="mb-40px">Another blending option is to all the brushstrokes to show. In the painting of trees above, I didn’t spend much time trying to <a href=https://orfun.com/acrylic class="color-bebe" target="_new">blend the colors</a>. I simply mix each color and apply it without fussing with it.</p>
```

**My regex is not very good:**

FIND: `<p class="mb-40px">.*?</p>(?!</a>)|(?!<a href=.*?">)`

Comment: The example is not valid HTML (e.g. hanging `</h2>`). You also shouldn't really parse HTML/XML with regexes. Any complex task will be almost impossible or unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<p class="mb-40px">|\G).*?\K(?:<a href=.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!/?p).)+?>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    <p class="mb-40px">     # literally
  |                       # OR
    \G                      # restart from last match position
)                       # end group
.*?                     # 0 or more any character
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
(?:                     # non capture group
    <a href=.+?</a>         # <a href=...
    (*SKIP)(*FAIL)          # skip this match and consider it has failled
  |                       # OR
    <(?:(?!/?p).)+?>)       # any tag that is not </p>
)                       # end group
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: almost good. Please see this text, test yout regex, and please write a better version :)  https://pastebin.com/SbVb8Tg0

Comment: @Justme: You should give more test cases **in your question**. But you could try: `(?:<p class="mb-40px">|\G).*?\K(?:<a href=.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!/?p).)+?>)` with `. matches newline` checked.

Comment: please add this new answer as an alternative for the first regex you made !

Answer (score 0):

**FIND:** `(?:<p class="mb-40px">|\G).*?\K(?:<a href=.*?>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?!/?p|/?a)[^>]*>)`

**REPLACE BY:** `LEAVE EMPTY`

**OR**

**FIND:** `(?:<p class="mb-40px">|\G).*?\K(?:<a href=.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!/?p class="mb-40px">|/p>).)+?>)`

**REPLACE BY:** `LEAVE EMPTY`

**OR:**

**FIND:** `<p class="mb-40px">(?:[^<]+|<(?!/?[ap]|a\s[^>]>))?</p>(*SKIP)(FAIL)|<(?!/?[ap]|a\s[^>]>)[^>]+>`

**REPLACE BY:** `LEAVE EMPTY`

---

The element [ap] is a character class that matches either 'a' or 'p'. Within regular expressions, using a character class allows you to specify a set of possible characters for a given position in the template.

In our case, [ap] is used in the <(?!/?[ap]|a\s[^>]*>) part, where we check for tags that start with '<' and are not followed by 'a' or 'p'. By using [ap], we indicate that we want the next letter after '<' to be either 'a' or 'p'. Thus, any tag that does not start with 'a' or 'p' will be included in the regular expression match and replaced.

I hope this explanation clarifies the use of the [ap] element in the proposed regular expression.